# HTML5 Input type time -- which part (hours or minutes) was selected or changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

In HTML5, the input type `time` provides an input element for a time consisting of hours and minutes.

When clicking the `hour` part it will be selected and by clicking the increment arrow we can increase the value, and the same for minute also...

Can we get which part (i.e. hour or minute) is selected or changed?

Comment: Post your code. What you've tried.

Comment: Can also see this http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

Comment: You may want to use jquery instead to get the part that you need.

Comment: Fork this to have something to play with:  http://jsfiddle.net/7G3xS/3/

Comment: Here's what I see. Setting a `.select` handler in jQuery does not produce any events.  Setting a `.change` handler in jQuery provides an event the first time the widget is completely filled out, as in `01:03 AM`, and then provides a change event at every change thereafter.  I didn't see a field to direct me to exactly what had changed, but there are a lot of fields and I did not look thoroughly.  However, some smart coding could figure that out from the previous value...

Comment: You could check that on `change` event. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AFdCC/

Comment: @abhitalks That looked pretty good to me, why dont you post it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @Paul, added as an answer. Actually I wasn't very sure about the question itself, and thought this wouldn't be worthy as an answer.  I kept looking at the specs to find if it was available natively. But, unfortunately it isn't. It is left upon the browser implementations to implement the UI their own way hence the pattern could change.

Comment: Can be fixed by a reasonable edit to the question... done.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @Paul above in the comments, the `onselect` event doesn't work in such a case. You could however hook the `change` event and split the HH and MM portions to find out which one was changed.

Something along these lines:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AFdCC/***

*Relevant Code*: (very crude but will give you the idea)

```
// handle change event on the element
$("#tm").on("change", function() {
    /*
        cache the default value of the element, 
        this is the value initially applied to the input.
    */
    var before = this.defaultValue;
    var after = this.value;  // current value i.e. changed value
    var partsBefore = before.split(":"); // make an array of old value
    var partsAfter = after.split(":"); // make an array of new value
    if (partsBefore[0] == partsAfter[0]) { // compare old and new value arrays
        if (partsBefore[1] == partsAfter[1]) {
             $("#result").text("Nothing changed"); // this will actually never fire
        } else {
            $("#result").text("Minutes changed");  
        }
    } else {
         $("#result").text("Hours changed");
    }
    this.defaultValue = after; // <-- This is important. 
    /*
        defaultValue holds only the value which was initially applied, 
        so it will always return the initial value. Hence, it is required to
        overwrite it here with the current value so that it could be compared on
        next change.
    */
});
```

In fact, you could also re-factor it out to a utility function which you could call on whenever required.